# SslStream Class Review

Tags: c#

I have created an SslStream Abstract Class for my Client and i want you to review and enhance it for me if needed

SecureStream.cs

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Security;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Program.Connections.Packets;
using Program.Core.Misc;

namespace Program.Connections.Network
{
    public abstract class SecureStream
    {
        private static readonly byte[] Buffer = new byte[0x1f80];
        private const string IpAddress = "192.168.1.65";
        private readonly int _port;
        private readonly Socket _socket;
        private SslStream _sslStream;

        public abstract void Receive(byte[] buffer);
        public abstract void Error(Exception e);

        protected SecureStream(int port)
        {
            _socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            _socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.KeepAlive, true);
            _socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.DontLinger, true);
            _port = port;
        }

        public void Connect()
        {
            _socket.BeginConnect(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(IpAddress), _port), Authenticate, null);            
        }

        private async void Authenticate(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            try
            {
                var onCertificateValidationCallBack =
                    new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(
                        OnCertificateValidation);
                _sslStream = new SslStream(new NetworkStream(_socket, true), false, onCertificateValidationCallBack);

                await _sslStream.AuthenticateAsClientAsync(IpAddress);
                if (!_sslStream.IsAuthenticated) throw new Exception("not^authenticated");

                do
                {
                    var size = await _sslStream.ReadAsync(Buffer, 0, Buffer.Length);
                    if (size == 0) throw new Exception("invalid^size");
                    var buffer = new byte[size];
                    Native.MemoryCopy(Buffer, buffer, (uint)buffer.Length);
                    Receive(buffer);
                    Array.Clear(Buffer, 0, Buffer.Length);

                } while (_sslStream.CanRead);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Error(e);
            }
        }

        internal async Task Send(PacketWriter writer)
        {
            var buffer = writer.GetWorkspace();
            await _sslStream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        }

        private static bool OnCertificateValidation(object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslpolicyerrors)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

CoreServer.cs

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Program.Connections.Network
{
    public sealed class CoreServer : SecureStream
    {
        public CoreServer(int p) : base(p) { }

        public override void Receive(byte[] buffer)
        {
            //TODO: Handle The Buffer
        }

        public override void Error(Exception e)
        {
            //TODO: Add Error Writer.
            MessageBox.Show(
                string.Format("Disconnected from the server."),
                string.Format("Connection Error"), MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            Environment.Exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

And i Simply Execute it using

```
var coreServer = new CoreServer(/*port*/);
coreServer.Connect();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
new byte[0x1f80]
```

I think using decimal would be more readable here. And I don't understand why is your buffer 8096 bytes, usual sizes are powers of two, like 8192.

```
IpAddress = "192.168.1.65"
```

This looks like a perfect example of something that should be configurable, not set in stone. You should accept the IP address in the constructor, like you already do with port number.

```
public abstract void Receive(byte[] buffer);
public abstract void Error(Exception e);
```

I'm not sure I like the use of inheritance here. I think using events, or something like that would make more sense here.

```
_socket.BeginConnect(…)
```

I don't like that you're using the old Asynchronous Programming Model when you could (and do in other parts of your code) use `async`-`await`. Unfortunately, `Socket` doesn't expose `await`able methods, but [there are ways around that](https://web.archive.org/web/20160712221103/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/12/15/10248293.aspx).

```
private async void Authenticate(IAsyncResult ar)
```

I think `Authenticate` is not a very good name for this method, it does much more than just authentication.

```
throw new Exception("not^authenticated")
```

You shouldn't throw `Exception`, you should instead create a custom class that derives from `Exception` and use that. And the exception message should be human-readable, not some error code like it seems in your case. If you need to differentiate different errors, either have different exception types for them, or add a property for that to your custom exception.

```
if (size == 0) throw new Exception("invalid^size");
```

When `ReadAsync()` returns 0, it's not invalid size, it means the end of the stream was reached, so you should act accordingly.

```
Native.MemoryCopy(Buffer, buffer, (uint)buffer.Length);
```

Why are using some custom memory copying method here? Do you have some reason for not using [`Buffer.BlockCopy()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.buffer.blockcopy?view=net-6.0)? Also, why are you even doing the copying here? It seems you class is intended only for limited use (since you have a constant IP address), so couldn't you make sure the buffer isn't used after `Receive()` returns, so you didn't have to copy at all?

```
return true;
```

I'm no expert on security, but I think you should perform at least some checks of the certificate here. Otherwise, your class isn't really a “secure stream”.

```
MessageBox.Show(…);
```

You shouldn't mix code like this with GUI code, they should be separated.

Comment: i am throwing an exception on reading 0 because it means that it is disconnected. Also i am using MemoryCopy because it is much faster than regular BlockCopy

Comment: Instead of always returning `true` from `OnCertificateValidation` it's  better to return `sslpolicyerrors == SslPolicyErrors.None`. Example here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.security.remotecertificatevalidationcallback(v=vs.110).aspx